# Moving around pointers in a linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Question: Given a linked list with three pointers: first points to the first node, second to the third and third to the last node. Return a single pointer to the same list so that the 5th is the first and the the first is the last.

This was a question given to us in class, i'm having trouble understanding the question, but here is my attempted solution.

```
//List is the first pointer
//p is the second pointer (pointing to the third node)
//q is the last pointer (pointing to the last node)

 R = p -> next //R, a name to a pointer i gave that is between p and q
 p -> next = R -> next // don't even know what this means but wrote it down anyways
```

after this I am stuck, any help is appreciated but I would appreciate the full solution.

I would further appreciate a solution that utilizes STL

Comment: _'I would further appreciate a solution that utilizes STL'_ This would be simply using [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: That's correct, but I don't know how to use std::list to accomplish this

Comment: @user3786689 Do you have to use raw pointers, or can we just make a reference to the list and use its built-in functions instead?

Comment: @Namfuak Any Method actually, I would love to see both if possible.

Comment: @user3786689 That's documented for [`std::list::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) method.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Maybe i'm not understanding the question, does the question actually want us to move nodes around or just the raw pointers. I'm sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @user3786689 _'or just the raw pointers'_ Looks like so, yes. (moving the raw pointers **will** essentially move _nodes_)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So I guess my request for an STL method doesn't apply here.

Comment: @user3786689 _'So I guess my request for an STL method doesn't apply here.'_ Yup. Now you've got it!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well I would really appreciate it if you provided a solution using raw pointers

Comment: @Namfuak Raw Pointers

Comment: @user3786689 That's essentially what you already have. And asking for _'Can I has codez plz'_ is off topic on this site.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not asking anyone to do my homework, I just need a solution to this problem so I can follow the logic and approach all my other problems more easily.

Comment: So elaborate on what you don't understand in particular from what you have already. And do this by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24470950/edit) please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
list *tmp, *tmp2, *pf, p3, pl;    //pf: first, p3: 3rd, pl: last;

tmp = p3->next->next;    //pointer of the 4th element to the 5th;
p3->next->next = tmp->next;    //4th element now pointing to the 6th (since 5th moves to the beggining);
pl->next = pf;    //make the first the last;
tmp2 = pf->next;    //save the pointer to the 2nd;
pf->next = NULL;    //pf is now last (-> pf->next has to be NULL);
tmp->next = tmp2;    //old 5th now pointing to the 2nd (as it should be the first);
pf = tmp;    //make the 5th the first -> this is what you want to return;
```

What is basically done here: You take out the 5th element (its pointer) out and therefore you have to connect 4 with 6. Now you put the first at the end. This is pretty easy since last->next is NULL anyway. The last thing you have to do now is making the 5th the 1st. For that you need to make it point to the 2nd. And that's it. As far as I understood you should wrap this also in a function which returns first then.